# Delete a row from the database via ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, symfony

I have this javascript function to delete the row but the function is not working

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('table#example td a.delete').click(function()
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            var data = 'id=' + id ;
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

            $.ajax(
            {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "supprimerkpi",
                   data: data,
                   cache: false,

                   success: function()
                   {
                        parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});

                        // sets specified color for every odd row
                        $('table#example tr:odd').css('background',' #FFFFFF');
                   }
             });
        }
    });
```

and in my page html:

```
<a href="#" class="delete" style="color:#FF0000;">
```

in my controller

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AdminBlogBundle:Condkpi'); $id=$this->getRequest()->query->get('id');
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$uti=$repository->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
$em->remove($uti);
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the "id" via `POST` method. So, you need to change:

```
$id=$this->getRequest()->query->get('id');
```

into:

```
$id=$this->getRequest()->request->get('id');
```

Also, you could change:

```
$uti=$repository->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
```

into:

```
$uti=$repository->find($id);
```

.. as `find()` searches entity using the primary key...

On a side note, what is "supprimerkpi"? That can't be a valid destination URL, right? :)

Comment: "supprimerkpi" route method in controller

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that... sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `routing.yml`

```
delete_data:
    path:     /delete
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:delete}
```

in your ajax call url parameter change that according to this

```
var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');

var data = 'id=' + id ;


 var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

        $.ajax(
        {
               type: "POST",
               url: "{{ path('delete_data') }}",
               data: {id :id },
               cache: false,

               success: function()
               {
                    parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});

                    // sets specified color for every odd row
                    $('table#example tr:odd').css('background',' #FFFFFF');
               }
         });
```

in your `AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/DeafultControlller.php`

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request)
{
   $id = $request->get('id');
   $repository = 
    $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AdminBlogBundle:Condkpi'); 
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
   $uti=$repository->findOneById($id);
   $em->remove($uti);
   $em->flush();
}
```